# Improving this regex to include what it matches until it matches a certain character

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

Can someone please help me improve this regex so that it captures everything that starts with http://, https://, or www and then continues until it reaches a ' or ". It includes punctuation and is case-insensitive.

Here is the regular expression right now:

```
(wwww|https?://)
```

Comment: Rather than try to write a regex to do this, why don't you find an existing solution in your host language?

Comment: @AndyLester true, I'm looking for that right now. What I am trying to do is get the value of the href attribute for all anchors in a string. By anchor, I mean an html anchor.

Comment: So you're actually parsing HTML.  Then go and get an HTML parser.  http://htmlparsing.com/ gives you examples for many different languages.  What is your language you're using?

Comment: yes, i'm parsing HTML. I'm using PHP. Thank you very much for the link! That helps a lot! Now, if only I could get this regex working and then I'll use the parser in addition and I'll be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^'"]*/i
```

I escaped the slashes since they could conflict if you use `/.../` notation. `[^'"]` is an inverted character class that allows everything but quotes.

Edit: I removed the caret to match any occurrence of the pattern, `:?` to make the group non-capturing.

Comment: Ah, I see that the slashes are not escaped. Before I implement them, I'm trying them in this regex tester ( http://regexpal.com/ ) and although yours makes more sense it is not matching according to that tester. I want everything after a http://, https://, or www. until, but not including, ' or ".

Comment: How are you testing it? That expression works for me in egrep. $ echo "www.google.com/asdf'dontmatchme" | egrep -oi "^(https?:\/\/|www)[^'\"]*" -- note - the quote needs escaping.. if quoted :-)

Comment: Ah, now it is working. That is odd. Except for me, in regexpal.com, it only matches the first occurrence. I need it to match every.

Comment: Remove the caret and retry. Are you using preg_match_all ?

Comment: Hmm, nope. I'm trying it against this string in regexpal.com www.google.com' http://www.google.com' https://www.google.com/' stackoverflow.com . Maybe the site isn't working?

Comment: The site might only perform the first match. That's why I asked about preg_match_all, that function will return all matches of an expression on a string.

Comment: I tried it with preg_match_all and I am getting nothing in the array that I add the matches into. So, I'm interpreting that as no matches... Here is the code: `preg_match_all( '(https?:\/\/|www)[^\'\"]*', $content, $matches ); print_r($matches);`

Comment: For the function call you need to add slashes `/.../` or something else, you can't just paste in a regex.

Comment: Slashes? Where? I thought one could use a plan regex... Please explain how I should write the preg_match_all function.

Comment: An example is provided here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php . `|` is used to delimit the regex from the modifier.

Comment: Ah, okay. So, which notation is proper in this case "/regex/" or "|regex" ?

Comment: Just try it, both work, you need to escape whatever you use as delimiter if you are using it inside the regex. I updated the expression in the answer with `/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@(www|https?://).*?(?=['"])@i
```

The `.*?` makes the quantifier reluctant so it will stop at the first quote rather than the last.

Comment: It isn't even matching things that start with http(s):// or www let alone stopping at the ' or ".

Comment: The slashes are not escaped.

Comment: @IMUXIxD sorry I used slashes as delimiters

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will work:

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www)[^'"]*
```

You can walk through the details of the match at [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28?%3ahttps?%3a%5C/%5C/%7Cwww%29%5B%5E%27%22%5D%2a&flags=i&str=http://www.google.com/search%22%20and%20another%20one%20hTtp://www.facebook.com).